# How to create region using CLLocation framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi friends can any one help me in creating region that cover the view in-front of my camera using CLRegion class

Answer (score 0):

Manish,

The CLRegion class (as of the current SDK) only supports circular regions.  You could use the present location and the compass heading to determine where the camera is pointing and then place your CLRegion accordingly, but I doubt that that will do what you want -- could you tell us a little more about your use case?

Comment: yaa i also search on it and CLRegion class will not work for this because it create circular region so do you have any other idea for creating region

Comment: MY case is as follow.                                                 1. i want to display the information of object say house that come in the front of my camera                                                                2.i do not want to display the information of house that do not come in front of my camera or can say want to create square region